# Existence of norm for polynomials?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> We know the following for a normed space $X$: Every proper subspace $S\subset X$ has empty interior.

Now, is it possible to use essentially this statement to show that there is no norm $\vert\vert\cdot\vert\vert$ so that $(P(\mathcal R)),\vert\vert\cdot\vert\vert)$ is a Banach space where $P(\mathcal R)$ is the vector space of all real polynomials?

Answer (score 2):

Note that a Banach Space can't have a denumerable Hamel Basis the proof of which requires us to use that **interior of every proper subspace of a normed space is empty**.

But $P$ has one such namely $\{1,t,t^2,\dots\}$

Comment: thanks but I think the statement should be used in a more direct way. I personally never heard of such an result you mentioned above)

Comment: @JonasMeyer; got it right.Edited

Answer (score 1):

Here one uses Baire category theorem: Write 
$$
\mathcal P = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty span \{1,t,\dots, t^i\}.
$$
Each of the spaces $span \{1,t,\dots, t^i\}$ is finite-dimensional, hence closed. If $\mathcal P$ would be a Banach space, at least one of these finite-dimensional (and thus proper) subspaces of $\mathcal P$ would have non-empty interior, which is absurd due to the statement in your question.

Comment: Very nice. And applying this method  to any countable subset of a Banach space, it shows why an infinite-dimensional Banach space can't have a countable Hamel basis.